# Xml проверка элемента на существование

Tags: c#

Как можно проверить xml элемент на существование.

Comment: Если SelectSingleNode вернула null, то такого элемента нет

Comment: XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("response/user/mission/item[id=21]/count");
                        if (node.InnerText != null) { 
                        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText)));
                        }
                        

Ошибку возвращает =(

Comment: Пример приведите, того что вы там делаете. Структуру xml покажите, и чего хотите добиться.

Comment: var doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml("<lol></lol>");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("response/user/mission/item[id=21]/count"); if (node.InnerText != null) { BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText))); }

xml тут не важен, мне нужно сделать проверку, есть элемент в xml или ,нет

Comment: 1) Проверяйте на null node, а не InnerText.
2) Если физически узел в документе есть, но возвращается null проверьте ваш запрос xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузить XML в `XmlDocument` и вызвать [`XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) с соответствующим xpath - если результат вызова `null` - элемента нет. Если не `null` - элемент есть.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.LoadXml("<someXml></someXml>"); 
if (doc.SelectSingleNode("response/user/mission/item[@id=21]") != null)
{
    // элемент есть
}
{
    // элемента нет
}
```